# Detecting with Javascript whether a Browser supports Web Open Font Format (Woff) or not

Tags: javascript, jquery, webfonts, woff

i have to detect with JS (jQuery) wether a browser supports Woff and then add a class to the body. 
Something like this:

```
    if(woffIsSupported){

    $('body').addClass('modern');

    }
```

is this somehow possible? Thank you for your answers.

Comment: Why not just add the style and let the CSS fall back to some default font if the web font can't be used?

Comment: There are some limitation with such a fallback: for example, when using a custom font to render icons. A workaround in that case could be using the `content` CSS attribute (by violating the separation of content and style of course).

Comment: I need the same function. My web app needs to support the default Android 2.2 browser, and that doesn't use the fallback TTF font. (Tries to load the WOFF instead - this format isn't supported - and all the text becomes invisible as a result.)

Answer (score 4):

There's a function on [this post](http://paulirish.com/2009/font-face-feature-detection/) called `isFontFaceSupported` that checks for support based on browser features (the good way, i.e. not relying on the user agent string).

Copy that function and your code can become:

```
if(isFontFaceSupported()) {
  $('body').addClass('modern');
}
```

---

Here is the function from the post:

```
/*!
 * isFontFaceSupported - v0.9 - 12/19/2009
 * http://paulirish.com/2009/font-face-feature-detection/
 *
 * Copyright (c) 2009 Paul Irish
 * MIT license
 */

var isFontFaceSupported = (function(){


    var fontret,
        fontfaceCheckDelay = 100;

      // IE supports EOT and has had EOT support since IE 5.
      // This is a proprietary standard (ATOW) and thus this off-spec,
      // proprietary test for it is acceptable.
    if (!(!/*@cc_on@if(@_jscript_version>=5)!@end@*/0)) fontret = true;

    else {

    // Create variables for dedicated @font-face test
      var doc = document, docElement = doc.documentElement,
          st  = doc.createElement('style'),
          spn = doc.createElement('span'),
          wid, nwid, body = doc.body,
          callback, isCallbackCalled;

      // The following is a font, only containing the - character. Thanks Ethan Dunham.
      st.textContent = "@font-face{font-family:testfont;src:url(data:font/opentype;base64,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)}";
      doc.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(st);


      spn.setAttribute('style','font:99px _,serif;position:absolute;visibility:hidden');

      if  (!body){
        body = docElement.appendChild(doc.createElement('fontface'));
      }

      // the data-uri'd font only has the - character
      spn.innerHTML = '-------';
      spn.id        = 'fonttest';

      body.appendChild(spn);
      wid = spn.offsetWidth;

      spn.style.font = '99px testfont,_,serif';

      // needed for the CSSFontFaceRule false positives (ff3, chrome, op9)
      fontret = wid !== spn.offsetWidth;

      var delayedCheck = function(){
        if (isCallbackCalled) return;
        fontret = wid !== spn.offsetWidth;
        callback && (isCallbackCalled = true) && callback(fontret);
      }

      addEventListener('load',delayedCheck,false);
      setTimeout(delayedCheck,fontfaceCheckDelay);
    }

    function ret(){  return fontret || wid !== spn.offsetWidth; };

    // allow for a callback
    ret.ready = function(fn){
      (isCallbackCalled || fontret) ? fn(fontret) : (callback = fn);
    }

    return ret;
})();
```

Comment: The question is about WOFF support detection. This checks if `@font-face` is supported - if I'm right - which is not the same. Is it possibble to check if `isWOFFSupported`?

Answer (score 0):

Because it's hard to test that I'm using just the browser detection:

```
//test ie 6, 7, 8
var div = document.createElement("div");
div.innerHTML = "<!--[if lte IE 8]><i></i><![endif]-->";
var isIe8orLower = !!div.getElementsByTagName("i").length;

if (!isIe8orLower && !navigator.userAgent.match(/Opera Mini/i)) {
    $('body').addClass('modern');
}
```

It matches the usage: http://caniuse.com/#feat=woff