# Detect WOFF support with JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, browser-feature-detection, woff

I have a situation where I’m using Data-URIs to load fonts and only want to use one file type, WOFF. It’s also critical that a fallback font is not used so I’m looking for a way to detect if WOFF is supported with JavaScript. Is it possible to detect WOFF (not WOFF2) support?

This question has been asked before ([Detecting with Javascript whether a Browser supports Web Open Font Format (Woff) or not](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7570211/detecting-with-javascript-whether-a-browser-supports-web-open-font-format-woff)) but the answers given and accepted were not about detecting WOFF support.

Comment: Try this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7570211/detecting-with-javascript-whether-a-browser-supports-web-open-font-format-woff

Comment: @sev Interestingly, the top answer to that question doesn't actually seem to answer the question...

Comment: @sev I have seen that but it looks like the answer they were after was actually font-face support.

Comment: @James Yea, I think the new answer posted should work for you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like the only browsers that don't support WOFF are IE 8, Opera Mini, and Android before 4.3: http://caniuse.com/#feat=woff

Then you can check for IE8 by seeing if `addEventListener` exists and Opera Mini by seeing if `operamini` exists:

```
// from http://stackoverflow.com/a/19572784/4338477
function getAndroidVersion(ua) {
    ua = (ua || navigator.userAgent).toLowerCase(); 
    var match = ua.match(/android\s([0-9\.]*)/);
    return match ? match[1] : false;
}

if ((document.all && !document.addEventListener) || 
        (!!window['operamini']) || 
        (parseFloat(getAndroidVersion() < 4.4)) {
    // IE 8, Opera Mini, Android 4.3 or lower: No WOFF support
} else {
    // Supports WOFF
}
```

Comment: What about earlier versions of Android?

Comment: It should check anything less than 4.4. The other answers in http://stackoverflow.com/a/19572784/4338477 go over different detection edge cases if that doesn't work